# How do I get rid of an extra row in my drop down box?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have looked for this here and other places and I can't fine a solution.
I am working on a page that has several drop down boxes for staff members. I have use sql to get the names from the database and it works fine, aside from one small error. I am getting an extra space between the default Select a Staff Member and the first name on the 2nd call to this (see pic).

[image]

This is the code I have for that section of the page.

```
    <select name='contact1' class="reqd">
       <?php 
          echo "<option value='0' class='reqd'>-- Select a Staff Member --</option>";
          do {
              echo "<option value='".$row_staff['staffID']."'>".$row_staff['Name'] . "</option>" ; 
          }while ($row_staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($staff));
       mysql_data_seek($staff, 0);
    ?>
    </select>
```

I am using the same sql statement for the request hence the mysql_data_seek($staff, 0);. I can't see anything that would cause it to have an extra space. If I put mysql_data_seek($staff, 1); that just skips the first person.

Any ideas on what I need to fix?

Comment: Have you tried using `while() { ... }` instead of `do { ... } while()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any particular reason why to use `do ... while` loop instead of (more common) `while`?

```
   mysql_data_seek($staff, 0);
   while ($row_staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($staff)) {
       echo "<option value='".$row_staff['staffID']."'>".$row_staff['Name'] . "</option>" ; 
   };
```

Comment: didn't think of that I was just using what had worked on a previous problem. Testing it now.